# Main difference between gulp vs webpack in angular 2?

Tags: performance, angular, webpack, gulp, load-testing

i have developed a small project for that i need to work with performance test and all, 
which one is best for performance and development and testing server aswell in webpack or gulp to deploy the angular 2 app in iis, what is the major difference between gulp and webpack?

Comment: The major difference is that they don't have the same purpose, webpack is a bundler, gulp is a task runner.

Comment: It's like comparing a car and a boat, which one is better ?

Comment: `Gulp` seems to be fit your requirement, however, webpack will serve as loader. but can't be compared, both serve different objectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not that is good or better, but you don't need gulp.

Just use [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) for development which uses webpack and if you need other build logic just add npm scripts.